# Error in Routing in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am  new to angular js
I was trying to load another html  dyamically, below is the code i was trying

My  Base HTML include

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="LoginModule">
<head>
<title></title>
<script src="Resource/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="Resource/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div ng-view></div>
<script src="Module/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and my app JS

```
var app = angular.module('LoginModule', []);

app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider
    .when('/login',
        {
            controller: '',
            templateUrl: '/Module/View/Login/Login.html'
        })
     .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/login' });
   });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your jquery and angular script in the body tag:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="LoginModule">
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div ng-view></div>
<script src="Resource/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="Resource/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="Resource/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="Module/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Also I would set `ng-view` with `ng-view=""`

```
<div ng-view=""></div>
```

EDIT:
You forgot to include the ngRoute module. Please look at the following plnkr to more detail: http://plnkr.co/edit/A5X4BNsnuXxhmgPVOXpv

```
var app = angular.module('LoginModule', ['ngRoute']);
```